# removing the elements having the given character from the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been looking for a way to search a given character in an arraylist's elements.But ı couldn't find any.Could you please help me a bit ?

Comment: Why not iterate over it?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can we see an example or some code, to clarify what exactly you mean?

Comment: Actually I have been writing Java codes for about 1 month and im new here.Could you please help me a bit more ? How can I iterate ?

Comment: Okay ,the question "Suppose that names arraylist contains names, which are of type String. Write a method in Java that removes the names having the given character from the arraylist. Use indexOf(int ch) method of String class, which returns the index (an integer value) within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1 if the character does not occur "

Comment: You need to attempt this question first & come back if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> listCopy = yourList.clone();
Iterator<String> it = listCopy.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    String element = it.next();
    if(element.contains(Character.toString(yourChar)){
        yourList.remove(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing? I don't think you can do this with a normal iterator.

Comment: Never mind hoaz, I fail at life for not checking the docs first :). Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I edited it so that removal is possible, but what hoaz points out is valid too.

Comment: Ümit Bilgin, don't forget to click accept next to broncoAbierto's name to mark it as a working solution.

Comment: thank you all for your helps.I have a  midterm about 7 hours later and it's going to help me a lot .Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a for loop? Or an enhanced for : each loop? Or maybe an iterator?

I like using for loops the best:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++)
{
    if(arraylist.get(i).equals(your item here))
        do something
    else
        do something else
}
```

Additionally are you sure you are looking for a character or a string? How is it possible to have an arraylist of characters? Please post the arraylist declaration code.

[EDIT]:

Since we are looking for a character in an arraylist of strings, this is the new code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++)
    {
        if(arraylist.get(i).indexOf(character) > -1)
            do something
        else
            do something else
    }
```

Comment: this is what Collection#contains for

Comment: Won't contains return a boolean and not an index? I think we are removing, so a boolean will not help us.

Comment: this is what Collection#remove for

Comment: Thank you for your help but im looking for a character in a String type  arraylist.

Comment: Will this not remove a single instance? I understand that this is possible, but if you would like to post the code then please make a new answer so I can understand better :)

Comment: sorry for that ,maybe I used your code in a wrong way .But broncoAbierto's code really worked